# How to get apps names list Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift4

I'm new to IOS developing and I've been looking for a way to get list of apps names installed on a device but from what I have found is that Apple removed this from Swift 4. Is it true and if so is there an alternative way to get them?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get list of installed apps on IOS device , but if you have the url Scheme you can check with `UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL` method whether an app is installed or not

Answer (score 0):

This was never a feature on iOS because it would seriously hurt a user's privacy if it was. The solution using [canOpenUrl](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622952-canopenurl) works is you know the url scheme for a certain app but in theory any app can subscribe to any scheme so there are no guarantees there either.